# gdal_merge.py cannot import gdal in Windows 7 Anaconda GDAL Installation

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge, importerror

I have an installation of GDAL through Anaconda that is mostly working, but it throws an `ImportError` whenever I run gdal_merge.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\gdal_merge.py", line 37, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
ImportError: No module named osgeo
```

I can import GDAL without error from my own scripts and commands, even within the above folder. Most of what I have read about similar issues is that they are usually related to the `PATH` environment variable, but as far as I can tell mine is pointing to all the right places:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2;C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;
```

I have 64-bit Anaconda for Python 2.7 installed on a Windows 7 system. My version of GDAL is 2.1.0, which I installed with the `conda install` utility. I set and tested my `GDAL_DATA` environment variable, and believe it to be correct:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\share\gdal
```

I have replaced my user name with `xxx` throughout.

Comment: People seem to have problems with GDAL on Anaconda, see for example https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6831.

Comment: Generally, I use Linux in my projects, however, I recently used **gdal_merge.py** in Windows and I got error.  After some time, I remembered that Windows syntax is only with **gdal_merge**. I hope that it can help.

Comment: It is gdal_merge.py even on Windows, but OSGeo4W delivers also gdal_merge.bat file that runs the python script as `@python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal_merge.py" %*  `

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the line to simply:

```
import gdal
```

I've had similar issues, that worked, no idea why.

Comment: I am on a new system now, and cannot test this answer. However, in my experience, GDAL should import with either `import gdal` or `from osgeo import gdal`. Also, I will note the error I cite above is not in my code, but rather in `gdal_merge.py`, which is part of the GDAL library.

Comment: It should, but I've had it fail to import with `from osgeo import gdal` because the system couldn't find osgeo. Editing `gdal_merge.py` is probably a bad idea but it's one I'd be tempted to try anyway. Hope your new system is working better!